For React Quill feild validation
<div className="col-sm-10">
            <ReactQuill
              id="other_detail"
              name="other_detail"
              theme="snow"
              className={`${
                formik.touched.other_detail && formik.errors.other_detail
                  ? "inputreactquill-error"
                  : ""
              }`}
              value={formik.values.other_detail}
              onChange={(value) => {
                formik.setFieldValue("other_detail", value);
                formik.validateField("other_detail"); // Manually trigger validation
              }}
              onBlur={() => formik.setFieldTouched("other_detail", true)}
              style={{ height: "180px", marginBottom: 5 }}
            />
            <div className="mt-5">
              {formik.touched.other_detail && formik.errors.other_detail && (
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{formik.errors.other_detail}</div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>

That is the way I use the react quill in this I use the "Formik" for validation and in this when I did not enter any content the validation message showed but when I added the content after that clear and removed content the validation message was not displayed.
I expect that when I remove and clear the content after adding the validation message should displayed.
